# Program read image and process it ends "reflecting" its components many times

Tags: c++

I am developing a program that reads an image from .tga file to do some processing in it and then write it in a new file.

The program reads the image byte by byte, convert from char to float to make possible do the required processing on it and throw it in a bidimentional vector of Pixels (a struct with three floats) with it's dimensions being equal to the width and height of the image.

Then do the required processing and proceed to convert it back to char to being able to write it back in a new file.

First I tried to read two images and write it back to see if the reading and writing parts were working. The new images generated were equal to the original ones. So far so good.

Then I implement one of the algorithms that I needed and checked the result.
The image was totally crazy, with the image elements being reproduced apprently four times in different positions of the image. I proceeded to analyze the algorithm and didn't find anything wrong.

Then I imagined a simple test to analyze it. I simply "erase" the image, making it all white while making a small area of it to became a black square.
But that is not what happened. Look at the link: http://s72.photobucket.com/user/john_smith140/media/z_zpsj5iw9hme.jpeg.html?sort=3&o=0

The supposed singular black square ends showing up five times and with strange colors (the first and the fourth square were something between violet and purple in the original targa file, but when I converted it to jpeg for being able to host them online, all became equal)

This is the simple code that makes this processing:

```
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
        Image [i][j].b = 255, Image [i][j].g = 255, Image [i][j].r = 255;
        if (i>=200 && i<=400 && j>=200 && j<=400) {
            Image [i][j].b = 0, Image [i][j].g = 0, Image [i][j].r = 0;
        }
    }
```

with image being a:

```
 vector< vector<Pixel> > Image (width, vector<Pixel>(height));
```

At first I thought that the error was in the algorithm but now seems clear that the error must be in the reading/writing part. Here the code for it:

```
void TGAManager::readDataBiVector (vector< vector<Pixel> >& Image, int size, int width, int height) {
char *b, *g, *r;
char tmp,tmp2,tmp3;
b=&tmp, g=&tmp2, r=&tmp3;
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
        fileReader.read (b, 1);
        fileReader.read (g, 1);
        fileReader.read (r, 1);
        Image [i][j].b = (float) tmp, Image [i][j].g = (float) tmp2, Image [i][j].r = (float) tmp3;
    }
}
}

void TGAManager::writeDataBiVector (const vector< vector<Pixel> >& Image, int size, int width, int height) {
cout << "writeDataBiVector" << endl;
char *b, *g, *r;
Pixel temp;
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
        char tmp  = char (Image [i][j].b); char tmp2 = char (Image [i][j].g); char tmp3 = char (Image [i][j].r);
        b = &tmp, g = &tmp2, r = &tmp3;
        fileWriter.write (b, 1), fileWriter.write (g, 1), fileWriter.write (r, 1);
    }
}
```

I really have no clue about what I am doing wrong and would like any help. If someone find necessary, I will post as many code as necessary.